# Creating Mouse Event for image labels in QT

Tags: qt, mouseevent, qlabel

I am working on an application using QT. I have a mainwindow on which i have an image label. I load an image to this imagelabel and now i want to draw over it. So, my question is- how do i create mouse events for this image label only without having to derive another class of QLabel and instantiating its object to my main window.

My project's due tomorrow and its the only thing i've got left to do. I'd really appreciate the help.

Sincerely, Aayush Shrestha.

Comment: Do you mean respond to mouse events? I do quite understand what creating a mouse event mean.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to create a class that inherits from QLabel to get mouse event, you need to use the [installEventFilter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#installEventFilter) function using the eventFilter event of one of your class.

Comment: thanks for this advice.... but when I use installEventFilter, the image in the label is not visible... Do you know how to fix this problem? It would be real helpful.. Thank You!!

Comment: Maybe you are catching an event like the paintEvent or showEvent and not release it to the widget. So Widget do not repaint itself.